# Apache HTTPClient dependency issue : POM

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having issue while using Apache HttpClient in my java application.

```
2019-02-11 07:09:18,270 ERROR [Call-Dequeue-Delegator] (HibernateUtil.java:275) - Building SessionFactory failed.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

It runs fine on my local machine but not on servers. Since it is a client application I'm not having details of server etc.

Following is my Code:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(20)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30).build();

        // Creating client with request configuration(timeouts) & disabling redirect following
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).disableRedirectHandling().build();

        String endpoint = this.getSOAPEndPoint();
        String queryParamWithSurveyData = addDataToQueryParam(endpoint, customRequestModel);
        endpoint += queryParamWithSurveyData;
        HttpRequestBase httpRequestWithoutBody = null; // Failing at this
```

In the above code it's failing at the last line & I'm surprised why not on first one since both (RequestConfig & HttpRequestBase) are imported from HTTPClient.jar

Following is my POM snippet

```
//Existing sample dependency
    <dependency> //Existing sample dependency
        <groupId>com.connectfirst.intelliqueue</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/couchbase/gson-2.3.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

// New dependencies added
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpcore-4.4.11.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I saw somewhere that HttpClient is dependent on some other JARs as well & therefore added the following dependencies as well but had no luck.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpcore-4.4.11.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/fluent-hc-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-cache-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-osgi</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-osgi-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient-win</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpclient-win-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/httpmime-4.5.7.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jna-4.5.2.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jna-platform-4.5.2.jar</systemPath>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The JAR gets created successfully on my local with maven clean install.
Any lead would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you running your application on the servers vs. your local machine?

Comment: @rmlan : On server I have access to bamboo, other settings are configured, which I'm not aware of. While on local run the command in intelliJ "clean install"

Comment: I suspect that your hibernate dependencies are finding their dependencies from somewhere other than the ones you are providing in your `lib` folder. It's likely that some of these dependencies in your lib are `provided` in the AS and they are not compatible with the hibernate dep versions. I would start by finding out which dependencies are provided in your environment and eliminating them from your lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you scoping to `system`? That would imply that the jars are on the classpath of the running application. If you switch that to compile, assuming you're packaging as a spring-boot JAR or WAR file, they will be included in the resultant artifact. Without that the application cannot find the dependencies you are working with.

The `scope` attribute dictates where dependencies should be placed on the classpath.

- compile - the artifact is available for reference by the project code and should be bundled (ostensibly) with the resultant artifact (e.g. embedded in WAR under WEB-INF/lib or spring-boot as BOOT-INF/lib)
- provided - the artifact is available for reference by the project source code but is not included in the resultant artifact (think JSP libraries in a web app, you want to defer to the container implementation).
- runtime - the dependency classes are not available for direct reference by the project source code but is referenced at runtime (think JDBC driver, you don't specifically use that you load it, traditionally, by reflection using the name).
- test - the dependency classes are available to sources in src/test/java (etc). IDEs are supposed to separate the references but not always the case (e.g. Eclipse). If you try to reference a `test` scoped dependency from src/main/java your code will not compile because the dependency is not available.
- system - The artifact in this case is explicitly located by path and is expected to be available at runtime within the consuming application's classpath.
- import - This is only supported within the dependencyManagement elements.

You can see the description from the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Comment: I've tried with compile as well, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: how are you packaging the application? what is the `packaging` element in your pom?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using correct java version on server.

Please note that as of 4.4, HttpClient requires Java 1.6 or newer. for httpClent after 4.4 version you need to use newer java versions (say java 11) .